# GRPC Connection Management in Golang

Tags: go, grpc, grpc-go

I am relatively new to GRPC and want to be sure that I am doing connection management correctly with golang.  I don't want to have to create a new connection for every call but I also don't want to create bottlenecks as I scale.

What I did was to create a single connection in the init function:

```
var userConn *grpc.ClientConn
var userServiceName string

func init() {
    userServiceName := os.Getenv("USER_SERVICE_URL")
    if userServiceName == "" {
        userServiceName = "localhost"
    }
    logging.LogDebug("userClient:  Connecting to: "+userServiceName, "")
    tempConn, err := grpc.Dial(userServiceName, grpc.WithInsecure())
    if err != nil {
        logging.LogEmergency("account_user_client.Init()  Could not get the connection.  "+err.Error(), "")
        return
    }
    userConn = tempConn
}
```

And then for each function I will use that connection to create a Client:

```
c := user.NewUserClient(userConn)
// Contact the server and print out its response.
ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), time.Second)
defer cancel()
r, err := c.GetUserFromTokenID(ctx, &user.GetUserFromTokenRequest{TransactionID: transactionID, OathToken: *oathToken})
//Handle Error and Response
```

is this an acceptable way to handle grpc connections?   Any recommendations on better ways?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, it's fine to have single GRPC client connection per service. Moreover, I don't see any other options here. GRPC does all the heavy lifting under the hood: for example, you don't need to write your own client connection pool (as you would do for a typical RDBMS), because it won't provide better results than a single GRPC connection.

However I would suggest you to avoid using global variables and init functions, especially for networking setup. Also you don't need to create GRPC client (`c := user.NewUserClient(userConn)`) every time you post a request to the GRPC service: this is just an extra work for garbage collector, you can create the only instance of client at the time of application startup.

**Update**

Assuming that you're writing server application (because it can be seen from the method you call on the remote GRPC service), you can simply define a type that will contain all the objects that have the same lifetime as the whole application itself. According to the tradition, these types are usually called "server context", though it's a little bit confusing because Go has very important concept of `context` in its standard library.

```golang
   // this type contains state of the server
   type serverContext struct {
       // client to GRPC service
       userClient user.UserClient

       // default timeout
       timeout time.Duration

       // some other useful objects, like config 
       // or logger (to replace global logging)
       // (...)       
   }

   // constructor for server context
   func newServerContext(endpoint string) (*serverContext, error) {
       userConn, err := grpc.Dial(endpoint, grpc.WithInsecure())
       if err != nil {
           return nil, err
       }
       ctx := &serverContext{
          userClient: user.NewUserClient(userConn),
          timeout: time.Second,
       }
       return ctx, nil
   }

   type server struct {
       context *serverContext
   }

   func (s *server) Handler(ctx context.Context, request *Request) (*Response, error) {
       clientCtx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(ctx, time.Second)
       defer cancel()
       response, err := c.GetUserFromTokenID(
          clientCtx, 
          &user.GetUserFromTokenRequest{
              TransactionID: transactionID,
              OathToken: *oathToken,
          },
       )
       if err != nil {
            return nil, err
       }
       // ...
   }

   func main() {
       serverCtx, err := newServerContext(os.Getenv("USER_SERVICE_URL"))
       if err != nil {
          log.Fatal(err)
       }
       s := &server{serverCtx}

       // listen and serve etc...
   }
```

Details may change depending on what you're actually working on, but I just wanted to show that it's much more better to encapsulate state of your application in an instance of distinct type instead of infecting global namespace.

Comment: Thank you very much, that is very helpful.  Follow up question if you don't mind.   How would you recommend setting up the connection then if not global?    I will have multiple functions all using the same connection.  That was the one part that I didn't understand in your suggestion.   Thanks again.

Comment: Right on!   Thank you very much.   That is a much cleaner way.   Really appreciate your help.

Comment: hi @Vitaly i'm a bit curious about this statement `However I would suggest you to avoid using global variables and init functions, especially for networking setup `. could you explain why would you avoid that? thanks

Answer (score 2):

A few things make this implementation work.

1. gRPC channel (i.e, `c` from `c := user.NewUserClient(userConn)`) is backed by a http/2 connection. It will automatically reconnect or retry connection when the connection is closed or dead.
2. http/2 supports messages to be sent concurrently within a single connection. Considering this scenario, service Order makes one product stock get, product stock update and product coupon change to service Product at a time. The three grpc requests can reuse the single http/2 connection, and grpc will process the data exchange concurrently. So it's okay to just use one connection, instead of creating three connections (like http/1) to achieve this.
3. To avoid premature optimization, one connection should be okay to start for a service. In case pool performance in future, consider creating one separate tcp connection (then separate http/2 connection) for hot spot grpc requests.

It might be good to keep connection alive, in case some proxy might kill the idle connection. See more explanation at https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/blob/master/Documentation/keepalive.md, and example code at https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/tree/master/examples/features/keepalive.

For gRPC vs http/2 connection, check https://grpc.io/blog/grpc-on-http2/#a-robust-high-performance-protocol and https://www.cncf.io/blog/2018/07/03/http-2-smarter-at-scale/.